# Pyspark StructType is not defined

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to struct a schema for db testing, and StructType apparently isn't working for some reason. I'm following a tut, and it doesn't import any extra module.

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>, NameError("name 'StructType' is not defined",), <traceback object at 0x2b555f0>)
```

I'm on spark 1.4.0, and Ubuntu 12 if that has anything to do with the problem. How would I fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Did you import `StructType`? If not

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
```

should solve the problem.

Answer (score 17):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
```

That would fix it but next you might get `NameError: name 'IntegerType' is not defined` or `NameError: name 'StringType' is not defined` ..

To avoid all of that just do:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

Alternatively import all the types you require one by one:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, IntegerType, StringType
```

All Types: [Apache Spark Data Types](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataTypes.html)